# Example of two conics intersecting in projective space in exactly 3 points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I'm trying to come up with an example of two irreducible conics in $\mathbb{P}^2$ that intersect in exactly 3 points.
In the Euclidean plane, this would be straightforward as I could take:
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=1, y=-x^{2}+1$$

but I'm not sure how to achieve this in projective space.

Comment: Hint: Homogenise your polynomials

Comment: @Mummytheturkey ok so $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =0$ and $yz+x^2 -z^2 = 0$ intersect in 3 points?

Comment: Yes, it suffices to show they do not meet on the line at infinity. For a more high powered proof you could invoke Bezout (including the multiplicity statement)

Comment: Just for clarity, you are talking about projective **plane**, not space - right?